# ruby parameters returning themselves

Tags: ruby, object, parameter-passing, ruby-2.3

I'm running Ruby 2.3.1 x64 on Windows 10 x64.

My code:

```
class Credentials

  attr_reader :username, :password

    def initialize(username = nil, password = nil)
        @username = username
        @password = password
        get_credentials if !@username || !@password #Gets credentials if none are specified
    end

  def get_credentials
    @username = ask("Username:  ") { |q| q.echo = true }
    @password = ask("Password:  ") { |q| q.echo = "*" }
  end

end
```

Ignore the get_credentials wackyness, it's a gem called Highline that I'm using to hide input for security reasons.

When I do the following:

```
$user = Credentials.new(username: "foo", password: "bar")
```

I get this return:

```
#<Credentials:0x000000038ecf30 @password=nil, @username={:username=>"foo", :password=>"bar"}>
```

Likewise, calling $user.username returns the following:

```
{:username=>"foo", :password=>"bar"}
```

when it should be returning:
    "foo"

and calling $user.password returns nil.

Can someone tell me why in the name of Henry Hamilton this is happening?! I've used hashed parameters many times, and it always works just fine. Why is it stuffing every parameter setting into a single parameter?

Comment: Screwed up, put that title temporarily thinking I would fix it after, then forgot, and now I can't change it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a method/constructor you don't pass arguments by name but by value just like any other programming language, So :

```
$user=Credentials.new("foo","bar")
```

Will do what you want.

This is the default in almost every programming language, your question should have been "How did this work", it worked because ruby is dynamically typed and the syntax `key1: val1,key2: val2,...` is the new hash syntax(since ruby 1.9), a hash is a key-value data structure , so your :

```
$user=Credentials.new(username: 'foo',password: 'bar')
```

Is actually calling the constructor with one argument only which is username with the value `{username: 'foo',password: 'bar'}` and because initialize is defined with default arguments , `password` got a value of `nil`.

Now if you do want to pass arguments by name, you have to define the constructor like so :

```
def initialize(username: nil,password: nil)
//code
end
```

After that you can do :

```
$user=Credentials.new(username: 'foo',password: 'bar')
```

And expect it to behave like you want.

Notice that keyword arguments(that is passing arguments by name) are introduced in ruby 2, also notice that you can achieve the same with a constructor that accepts one parameter which is a hash like this :

```
def initialize(params={})
//code
end
```

But this way doesn't limit the number of arguments nor their names(you can call `Credentials.new(fooprop: 'foovalue')` and no error will be thrown), also it needs some change in code.

The Keyword arguments feature is found in some programming languages and it's useful when the function have many parameters or to make it clear for the programmer what is the parameter for.

Comment: Thanks! For any Google passersby, the issue with my code was the use of (username = nil, password = nil) instead of (username: nil, password: nil). This is the syntax for a standard default parameter, NOT a hash. Because of this, when I was instantiating the object with Credentials.new() and specifying a hash for the parameters, it was really just storing that hash in the first parameter variable.

Comment: To further simplify, if anyone else is having this problem, just change 'def foobar(foo = nil, bar = nil)' to 'def foobar(foo: nil, bar: nil)'. It's that syntactical difference which tells the method whether or not it is going to use standard sequential parameters or a hash for its input.

Answer (score 2):

```
$user = Credentials.new(username: "foo", password: "bar")
```

You are passing just one parameter to the initialize method, a hash. The hash for the username attribute and nil for the password attribute. Try

```
$user = Credentials.new("foo", "bar")
```

Or, if you really want keyword arguments then

```
def initialize(username: nil, password: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def initialize(params={})
    @username = params[:username]
    @password = params[:password]
    @username || @password || get_credentials #simply
end
```

And then:

```
$user = Credentials.new(username: "foo", password: "bar")
```

Comment: this answer doesn't limit the number of arguments nor their names